# Call setOnItemSelectedListener on expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an `expandableListView`, By default I want the first `parentgroup` i.e. position 0 to be selected. So that it calls my `setOnItemSelectedListener`. Here is how I am setting my adapter and select listener:

```
adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                lstEpisodes, list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "focus on: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

This is the xml layout of listview:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/exlist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:childDivider="#FFFFFF"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:groupIndicator="@null" >
                <requestFocus />
            </ExpandableListView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
list.setSelection(0);
list.requestFocus();
list.invalidate();
```

How do I select the first row of the `listview`, a default selection when adapter is set..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps a hacky way to solve the problem but it will work.  Capture your anonymous `OnItemSelectedListener` interface in a local variable assign it in the `setOnItemSelectedListener` method.  Instead of `setOnGroupClickListener` you can use `onGroupClick` on the local variable.  You have access to all of the variables needed to be passed in.  This should be used as a absolute last resort.

Comment: I have used `list.setSelectedGroup(0); list.requestFocus(); list.invalidate();` still no effect on the `listview`..

Comment: Welcome Justin. Please provide a few line of examples. It would be clearer for everyone.

Comment: @faizanjehangir what is it that you are trying to achieve with this? Why do you need that action to be in the `onitemselectlistener`

Comment: @JustinSlade I want the information of the item in `focus` to be populated on the `layout screen`. So by default I want the first row to be selected so that its information is displayed..

Comment: @faizanjehangir I think I understand what you are saying the user select an item and you populate some area with data of that item.  Why don't you use the `adapter` `getGroup` or `getChild` methods to get the data instead of try to get the `onItemSelected` method for the default data

Comment: I wanted to reuse the `onItemSelected`.. is it not possible? If not, then I go with your approach, still I will have to highlight the first group row of the `listview`..

Comment: After running out of other options, I ended up using the default setting of data at row 0.. Thanks